# svn update with php and ssl

Tags: php, linux, svn, ssl

I want to do SVN update easier - with calling PHP script.

I created PHP script:

```
$cmd = "svn update  https://___/svn/website /var/www/html/website/ 2>&1";
exec($cmd, $out);
```

As the user running the script is apache (not root), I get some permission errors.

If I change the owner of every directory to apache (or chrown everything to 777) I have another problem. Because I use https protocol user apache should permanently accept certificate of the svn server. I tried to do "su - apache" and accept certificate but OS says that "apache" is not valid user. I also dont know how could I accept certificate with exec() function.

Any idea? How can I make svn update-ing easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the error telling you that the user isn't a valid svn user? If apache is the user running httpd, you should be able to su to it. This is the script I use:

```
/usr/bin/svn --config-dir=/home/user/.subversion --username=svnuser --password=svnpass update
```

once the password is saved you can remove it from the command. Again, make sure the user/pass above is a valid SVN user.

Lately I've actually migrated to using Hudson for svn updates as you can schedule it as well as run manually and do a bunch of other tasks, plus you can view the svn logs for each commit as well as any console errors.

Comment: I manually changed /etc/passwd file for apache user (changing /sbin/nologin to /bin/bash). Than I was able to do "su - apache" and store certificates on the server. The only thing to do then is to use --config-dir option like ldg mentions above .. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [php svn functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) instead of (insecure) exec?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-auth-set-parameter.php has good examples for authentification options.

Comment: I will also try this option! Tnx

Comment: @stefgosselin How would you go about displaying error messages encountered after executing `svn_update`, `svn_commit`, etc.?

With `exec()` I don't have an issue getting and displaying exactly what went wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @nimph Unfortunately as you probably already saw, the svn_ functions return rev. number on success, false on failure. I don't know if you are religious, these functionsare to be used on 'faith' that svn is quite robust. if setup properly it should work fine, as long as your script has a proper connexion and proper credentials to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use getent apache on the shell. This will return the shell of apache. Most likely, it is /bin/nologin or /bin/false. Change this to /bin/bash. You'll also need to specify the home directory and create it on the file system.

**UPDATE:** getent apache will actually return the entry in the /etc/passwd file for the apache user. The last token in this string is the shell.

Comment: getent returned nothing. I manually changed /etc/passwd file for apache user.

Comment: I manually changed /etc/passwd file for apache user (for changing /sbin/nologin to /bin/bash). How do I specify home directory? Now I can do "su - apache" and update through svn but certificate is not stored even if I choose "permanently save certificate" ..

Comment: pass the `--config-dir=/path/to/svnconfig` argument both when you do it manually and in your script.

Comment: I didn't know about the --config-dir option. I would have actually created /home/apache and put it in the /etc/passwd file. But the config-dir option is definitely better.